# Getting VI to auto syntax highlight and autoindent

Tags: tty, vi

I prefer using vi from tty1 as I hate GUI. I've just begun programming in C and would like to know how to get vi to auto indent for me. I would like the following code to appear just like the way I've typed with proper tab space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following lines in `~/.vimrc` (use vim :P)

```
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

It will turn on filetype detection and will automatically get the correct syntax and indentation.